# How to tell a browser to use HTML5's "Blob" interface and not a function by the same name in the application?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

In my web application I am using [`FileSaver.js`](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to download files directly from the browser using JavaScript. Now the `saveAs` function in this library expects an object of type [`Blob`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob). The problem I am running into is that I have another function by the name `Blob` defined in my application. So when I call `saveAs` function like below:

```
saveAs(new Blob(fileContents, { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'download.txt');
```

The browser assumes that the `Blob` object is my `Blob` object and not the HTML5's `Blob` interface.

Obviously one way to solve this problem is to rename my `Blob` function to something else (may be `CloudBlob`) however I am curious to know if somehow I can avoid doing that.

If it were in .Net world, I would have used fully qualified name (by prepending Namespace e.g. `FileAPI.Blob`). I am wondering if I could do the same with HTML5 `Blob` interface? If the answer is yes, then I would appreciate if someone can tell me what would that look like. If it is not possible, then I guess I am only left with the option to change the name of my `Blob` function to something else.

Comment: Is your `Blob` a global variable? Then it will be more difficult, that's why the global scope shouldn't be polluted.

Comment: It is indeed in global scope [rookie mistake on my part :(].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your Blob object, it overrides the original one because they are set at the same context.

The Browser `Blob` function can be accessed directly like

```
new Blob([], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
```

or

```
new window.Blob([], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
```

The new objects defined are put at the window namespace by default, that's why it is overwritten.
As you said, you can only rename your object to `CloudBlob`, but you can also create a namespace for you own object.
It could be like

```
var myAppNamespace = myAppNamespace  || {};
myAppNamespace.Blob = {
    // Your object code here 
};
```

Then you access to your own Blob like

```
myAppNamespace.Blob
```

That way you can differentiate the two functions

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many Thanks! I used your namespace concept for my Blob object.